# How to summon Number C107: Neo Galaxy Eyes Tachyon Dragon

Tags: yu-gi-oh

My favorite method of summon is the XYZ summon. However there's a monster I've been struggling to summon: it's my [Number C107: Neo Galaxy Eyes Tachyon Dragon](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Number_C107:_Neo_Galaxy-Eyes_Tachyon_Dragon).

I found this card called [Rank Up Magic Cipher Ascension](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Rank-Up-Magic_Cipher_Ascension) that let's you use an XYZ monster you control to summon an XYZ monster who's rank is 1 higher. However this card only works on "Cipher" monsters.

Can I still use this magic card on [Number 107: Galaxy Eyes Tachyon Dragon](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Number_107:_Galaxy-Eyes_Tachyon_Dragon) to summon it's chaos form? Or do I need to find another method?

Answer (score 3):

There are several Rank-Up-Magic Cards.  Barian's Force, Limited Barian's Force, Numeron Force and Argent Chaos Force come to mind.

http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Rank-Up-Magic

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use Rank Up Magic Cipher Ascension to summon Number C107: Neo Galaxy Eyes Tachyon Dragon as it does not include the word "cipher" in its name.

You can however use other other rank-up-magic cards listed below.

- [Rank-Up-Magic - The Seventh One](https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action?ope=2&cid=11087)
- [Rank-Up-Magic Admiration of the Thousands](https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action?ope=2&cid=11188)
- [Rank-Up-Magic Argent Chaos Force](https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action?ope=2&cid=11022)
- [Rank-Up-Magic Barian's Force](https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action?ope=2&cid=10541)
- [Rank-Up-Magic Numeron Force](https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action?ope=2&cid=10662)
  [Rank-Up-Magic Quick Chaos](https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action?ope=2&cid=11186)

For a full list of rank-up-magic cards please see [this link](https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action?ope=1&sess=3&page=1) on the yugioh card database.